# How import .py in python script

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

i'm trying to import the BeautifulSoup library directly in my python script, i can't install it because i'm using it in my Synology DS213+, so i'm trying to do this:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import urllib, urllib2

opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPHandler(debuglevel=0))
opener.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')]

ins = open( "str.txt", "r" )
array = []
for line in ins:
    array.append(line.strip())
ins.close()

for riga in array:
    print riga
    html = opener.open("http://www.mysite.com/?s="+riga)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
    soup.find_all('a')
    for link in soup.find_all('a'):
        print link.get('href')
```

but i receive this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "myscript.py", line 17, in <module>
    soup.find_all('a')
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

i can't understand why, i put BeautifulSoup.py in the myscript.py directory, and i import in this way:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
```

what is wrong?

Comment: What version of BeautifulSoup are you using? Often the module name is bs4, and you import it with something like, "from bs4 import BeautifulSoup"

Comment: `TypeError` is *not* `ImportError`. If it is all you've got then you've *already* imported `BeautifulSoup` successfully. Whether your installation is broken is another question.

Comment: I use beautifulsoup 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no import error here. You've already imported `BeautifulSoup` successfully.

Change `soup.find_all` to `soup.findAll` to fix the `TypeError`.

`.find_all()` is for [`beautifulsoup4`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/). You have [BeautifulSoup 3](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs3/documentation.html) installed. There is no `.find_all()` method in this version.

By default [`soup.something` will try to find `<something>` element in the html](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs3/documentation.html) if there is no existing `.something` attribute. `None` means there is no `<find_all>` element. See "Using tag names as members" section.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a folder named `BeautifulSoup` next to your `myscript.py` file.
2. Rename file `BeautifulSoup.py` to `__init__.py` and put it inside the `BeautifulSoup` folder.